# Gnatbench runs Ada program before compile

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ada, gnat

I have GNATbench installed in my Eclipse (Indigo) for coding in Ada; and for some odd reason, the program is first run and then compiled, which doesn't quite work when I update the code. I know the compiler works, because if I run the program manually it works fine; and if I hit run again, it runs with the proper changes made. A side note: I prefer using eclipse, and I'd rather not just compile from the command line. I am running Indigo on Ubuntu 11.4.

Comment: There are more alternatives to command line, for example GPS comes with GNAT.

Comment: Yeah, there's good integration with Emacs and make too. However, getting his Eclipse environment working better seems like a reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable "Build Automatically" in the Project menu and then build manually before running. This can be done using the Ctrl+B shortcut.

Comment: this works, but doesn't solve the problem at hand, which is how to make the auto build work... this is what i'm doing until it's fixed

Answer (score 0):

odd. is it actually running? Gnatbench does a syntax/file check everytime it saves. I'd make sure your gpr file is correct and that your project isn't nested within another eclipse project or else eclipse can act kinda weird.